# IntelliJ IDEA and Git: Update canceled: Rebase error

Tags: git

I have a branch checked out from remote which creates a local branch with the same name.
When I right click on a local branch and select update maybe after few few hours to get the changes from remote it fails to do so.

This is the error it gets:

> update canceled
>
> Rebase error:
>
> error: update_ref failed for ref
> 'refs/heads/production': cannot lock ref 'refs/heads/production': is
> at 88ffe649f53f3b9184c4f1794f4ebd7f5b0a1154 but expected
> 5f3a51224a7f509afe75a5b685d8fe0ee0a62ee5 error: could not update
> refs/heads/production

The weird thing is, it trying to lock incorrect ref. The remote branch is not the "production" like it says here in the error.

Another question is why is it even trying to rebase? All I want to do is get latest from remote branch.

Answer (score 1):

> Another question is why is it even trying to rebase?

I don't even know which "it" you're asking about here: IDEA, or Git?  Git will try to rebase whenever you or some other program running it ask it to do so.  But I can tell you what usually causes *this*, which appears to be coming from Git and not from IDEA:

> ```
> error: update_ref failed for ref 'refs/heads/production': 
>     cannot lock ref 'refs/heads/production': is at
>     88ffe649f53f3b9184c4f1794f4ebd7f5b0a1154 but expected
>     5f3a51224a7f509afe75a5b685d8fe0ee0a62ee5
> error: could not update refs/heads/production
> ```

(I split up the long initial line for StackOverflow display purposes.)

Git has a bad habit of storing *branch names* like `production` (full name `refs/heads/production`) as *files in a file system* (folder `ref` containing folder `heads` containing file `production`).  It *should* use a proper database for them, but instead uses the file system as a cheesy sort-of-database.

This bad habit works fine on your typical Linux or Unix-like system, where Git can have two files, one named `refs/heads/production` and one named `refs/heads/PRODUCTION`, that differ in case but in no other way.  But it *fails*, badly—with the above error—on your typical Windows or macOS system where the file system insists that a file named `PRODUCTION` in the `refs/heads/` folder *is the same file* as the file `production` in that same folder.  Git *needs* these two be *two different files*, and they just aren't.

This occurs when you have created one branch named `PRODUCTION` (or `Production`, or `proDUCtion`, or `prodcTiOn`, or whatever) as well as the branch named `production`.  To Git, ever case-change makes for a new and different branch name, so you can have four branches, named `Production`, `proDUCTION`, `PROduction`, and `productION`, that are all different from your `production` branch.  And in fact, this *works* ... somewhat.  It also *fails*, sometimes.  That's because Git *sometimes* stores the branch names in a flat-file database named `packed-refs` in the `.git` folder.  When it does that, the case sensitivity trick works to allow many different branches whose names *would* all be the same without case sensitivity.  But when Git starts breaking out the branches into individual files within `refs/heads/`, it stops working.

#### The solution

The solution to this problem is to *delete or rename* any branches that differ *only* in case.  Make sure you never create any such branch names.  Be sure not to create them locally, which is where the biggest problem is, but also be sure not to create them on GitHub or GitLab (which runs Linux systems and therefore all of this stuff works fine there, and then breaks sporadically when you import them back to your own system).

Use `git branch -a`, or whatever your IDE uses to display branches, to examine your branch names.  Rename `Production` or `PRODUCTION` if you have them, so that you have only the correct name, `production` (all lower case—I generally advise using only lowercase in branch names, to avoid this problem).

If this problem occurs in branch names *as found on the remote* (e.g., on GitLab or Bitbucket or whatever), you may need to use the web interface to the hosting system to rename the branches there.  Once those are fixed, use `git fetch --prune` locally—you may need to use it more than once in some (rare-ish) cases—to fix up your local copy.  Then take care not to re-create the problem: stick with all-lowercase letters always.