# error: update_ref failed for ref <branch> : cannot lock ref <branch> is at but expected

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-pull

git rebase --continue giving the following error

```
error: update_ref failed for ref 'refs/heads/replicating/realtimeAPIs': cannot lock ref 'refs/heads/replicating/realtimeAPIs': is at cee72b51627cd560f9f287e51262687f2d9c758f but expected 0734fcfe35d1aa7ee148e9c9bb94148261463319
error: could not update refs/heads/replicating/realtimeAPIs
```

Comment: Check to see if you have a branch with a similar name, but where the upper/lower-case mix is different: `replicating/realTIMEapis` for instance, or `REPLICATING/relatimeAPIs`. If so, that's the problem.

Comment: What have you done before `git rebase --continue` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70253306/7976758 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/72750596/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+error%3A+update_ref+failed+for+ref+cannot+lock+ref+is+at+but+expected